# How to get a year first date and last date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Need to get first date and last date of a year from passing only year number. It's almost look like below.

```
var year = 2016 //Any Year
var first_date = ? //From Year
var last_date = ? //From Year
```

Comment: Do you want to know the day of first and last date of the year?

Comment: First and Last date of the year is never gonna change right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var year = 2016 //Any Year
var first_date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
var last_date = new Date(year, 11, 31);

document.write(first_date);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(last_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate using **[`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** method, either with valid date string

```js
var year = 2016 //Any Year
var first_date = new Date('1 January ' + 2016 + ' 00:00:00') //From Year
var last_date = new Date('31 December ' + 2016 + ' 00:00:00') //From Year

document.write(first_date + '<br>' + last_date)
```

---

Or as parameter like [`new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) format

```js
var year = 2016 //Any Year
var first_date = new Date(2016 ,0,1) //From Year
var last_date = new Date(2016,11,31) //From Year

document.write(first_date + '<br>' + last_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want like this ?

```
var year = 2016 //Any Year
var first_date = new Date(year,0,1)
var last_date = new Date(year,11,31)
```